# No route matches [POST] in Ruby app I'm building

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, controller, routes

I'm trying to build an application that lets users create a trip with restful routing however, I'm encountering an issue when a user is logged in and they try to create a trip. 
I get "No route matches [POST] "/users/8/trips/new""

These are the routes:

```
resources :users do 
  resources :trips
end
```

This is the trip controller:

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @trip = Trip.new 
  end

  def create
    @trip = Trip.create(trip_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

This is the form to create a new trip. This is where I click submit and get the error:

```
<div class="trip_form">
<%= form_for :trip do |f| %>  

    <%= f.label :where, "Where?" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :where, placeholder: "Hawaii" %><br>

    <%= f.label :when, "When?" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :when, placeholder: "#" %><br>


    <%= f.label :price_per_person, "Price per person? (Approximately)" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :price_per_person, placeholder: "$550" %><br>

    <%= f.submit "Create Trip Idea"%>
<% end %>
```

These are the routes:

```
$ rake routes
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
    user_trips GET    /users/:user_id/trips(.:format)          trips#index
               POST   /users/:user_id/trips(.:format)          trips#create
 new_user_trip GET    /users/:user_id/trips/new(.:format)      trips#new
edit_user_trip GET    /users/:user_id/trips/:id/edit(.:format) trips#edit
 user_trip GET    /users/:user_id/trips/:id(.:format)      trips#show
           PATCH  /users/:user_id/trips/:id(.:format)      trips#update
           PUT    /users/:user_id/trips/:id(.:format)      trips#update
           DELETE /users/:user_id/trips/:id(.:format)      trips#destroy
     users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
           POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
  new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
 edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
      user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
           PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
           PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
           DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
      root GET    /                                        users#index
```

I thought I should be able to just fill out the trip new form and when I press submit for it to 
automatically communicate with the create method in the trip controller? When I do change :trip to @trip in the form I get this error:

NoMethodError in Trips#new

undefined method `trips_path'

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a tiny mistake in your `form_for` helper. It should be:

```
<%= form_for @trip do |f| %>
  ...
```

The helper will look at the `@trip` object and see that it is a new object (= not yet saved to the database) and thus will choose `POST /users/8/trips` as the form action.

By not handing an ActiveRecord Object to the helper, the generated HTML form has no action, so submitting the form will POST to the current path (which is the new-path)

*EDIT*

In order to let the helper choose a route for the nested resource situation you have, use:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @trip] do |f| %>
  ...
```

assuming that current_user is the user object you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, but when I change it to @trip I have another error:

NoMethodError in Trips#new
undefined method `trips_path'

Comment: ah I see. This is because you have no `ressources :trips` outside of the user scope. I will edit my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= form_for :trip do |f| %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_for [@user, @trip] do |f| %>
```

and because you're using nested resources you'll need this too

```
# controller
def new
  @user = User.find(1)
  @trip = Trip.new
end
```

More in the [documentation for form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Comment: Thank you! but when I change it to @trip I have another error:

NoMethodError in Trips#new
undefined method `trips_path'

Comment: @Hotconnection Ok, I missed that you're using nested resources, updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it :) how did you know you needed to write <%= form_for [@user, @trip] do |f| %> ? Is it because it's nested and to create a trip you have to have a user associated with it?

Comment: @PeterSorowka Or too much free time :)

Comment: @Hotconnection Yeah, that's spot on.